# Mysql: Set collation for view not working

Tags: mysql, database, collation, character-set

I want to set the collation of a view to default database. But the option is not available.
Even if I try to set anything other than that, the same is not reflected at columns as individually they have different collation.

Code:

```
create or replace view my_view as
select * from table_a a
inner join table_b b
on a.id = b.fk_id
collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

But if I query

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM my_view
```

the result set contains collation as **utf8mb4_general_ci**

Can anyone explain why this is happening? And how do I correct it?

More Info

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "char%";
```

| variable_name | value |
| --- | --- |
| character_set_client | utf8 |
| character_set_connection | utf8 |
| character_set_database | utf8mb4 |
| character_set_filesystem | binary |
| character_set_results | utf8 |
| character_set_server | latin1 |
| character_set_system | utf8 |
| character_sets_dir | /usr/local/mysql/share/charsets/ |

Comment: What charset and collation were established for the `DATABASE` you are in?  And of the connection?

Comment: @RickJames currently when I try to set collation as latin1_swedish_ci, it throws error as "COLLATION latin1_swedish_ci is not valid for CHARACTER SET utf8mb4" . The utf8mb4 is not present in any variables mentioned above, not sure how it came and how to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci` affects on joining condition only.

If you need to alter resultset collation then you must use separate columns list instead of asterisk with separate collation change (`CONVERT` function) or specifying for each string-type column.

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a0680c23d2a4227ad51af56ee2272aed)

Comment: when I try to collate with latin1_swedish_ci, it throws error : "COLLATION latin1_swedish_ci is not valid for CHARACTER SET utf8mb4". utf8mb4 is not present in any variables mentioned above, not sure how it came and how to solve this. Tried setting character_set_client, character_set_results, character_set_connection to latin1, still didn't work!

Comment: @Jake You need to change the charset, not only the collation - use explicit CONVERT() instead of collation specifying.

Comment: Can you please try it on the demo link you posted so that users get more clarity.